# Receber valor de variável em 'where in'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Em minha `procedure` tenho as seguintes variáveis:

```
@Codigo VARCHAR(MAX),@cont as int, @DataPago as VARCHAR(10)
```

Via aplicação C# estou passando os valores da seguinte forma:

```
y1.Parameters.Add("@Codigo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "2,4";
y1.Parameters.Add("@cont", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
y1.Parameters.Add("@DataPago", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "20/05/2015";
```

O problema é que eu estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2,4' to data type int.

Porém, quando coloco o valor direto na minha procedure, funciona, como abaixo:

```
WHERE P.RELATORIO in (2,4)
```

Comment: Tentou fazer isto? `y1.Parameters.Add("@Codigo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "2.4";` Se não é isto, coloque a *query* e detalhes mais o problema. Tá esquisito o que pretende, talvez por falta de informações completas.

Comment: Você está passando o código no `IN` do `WHERE`?

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma função para lhe ajudar nisso, segue o código abaixo para seu problema:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrByDelimiter]
(
    @String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1)
) 
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI)       
AS   
BEGIN      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return
END
```

E depois na sua query pode passar os valores com vírgula ou qualquer outro delimitador.

```
..
WHERE P.RELATORIO in (select items from [dbo].[SplitStrByDelimiter](@Codigo,','))
```

A função é útil evitando fazer manualmente em cada SP sua, podendo também utilizar outros delimitadores.

Comment: Solução perfeita. Me ajudará muito. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra opção é usar uma tabela como parametro

```
CREATE TYPE RelatorioType AS TABLE ( 
    Codigo int primary key
);
GO

/* Create a procedure to receive data for the table-valued parameter. */
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ConsultarRelatorio
    @Relatorio RelatorioType Readonly, 
    @cont int,
    @DataPago varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Pessoas P
    JOIN @Relatorio R ON P.RELATORIO = R.Codigo
    WHERE
        P.cont = @cont AND
        P.DataPago = @DataPago
END
GO
```

Então no codigo C#, no lugar de passar uma string '2,4', você passar um tabela com duas linhas.

```
var relatorio = new DataTable();
relatorio.Columns.Add("Codigo", typeof(int));
relatorio.Rows.Add(2);
relatorio.Rows.Add(4);

var pRelatorio = new SqlParameter("@Relatorio", SqlDbType.Structured);
pRelatorio.TypeName = "dbo.RelatorioType";
pRelatorio.Value = relatorio;

y1.Parameters.Add(pRelatorio);
y1.Parameters.Add("@cont", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
y1.Parameters.Add("@DataPago", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "20/05/2015";
```